how to bypass emulator detection from the smali script

.class public final Lcom/stripe/android/stripe3ds2/init/SecurityCheck$Emulator;
.super Lcom/stripe/android/stripe3ds2/init/SecurityCheck;
.source "SourceFile"


# static fields
.field public static final WARNING:Lcom/stripe/android/stripe3ds2/init/Warning;


.method public static constructor <clinit>()V
    .locals 4

    .line 1
    new-instance v0, Lcom/stripe/android/stripe3ds2/init/Warning;

    .line 2
    .line 3
    sget-object v1, Lcom/stripe/android/stripe3ds2/init/Warning$Severity;->HIGH:Lcom/stripe/android/stripe3ds2/init/Warning$Severity;

    .line 4
    .line 5
    const-string v2, "SW02"

    .line 6
    .line 7
    const-string v3, "An emulator is being used to run the App."

    .line 8
    .line 9
    invoke-direct {v0, v2, v3, v1}, Lcom/stripe/android/stripe3ds2/init/Warning;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/stripe/android/stripe3ds2/init/Warning$Severity;)V

    .line 10
    .line 11
    .line 12
    sput-object v0, Lcom/stripe/android/stripe3ds2/init/SecurityCheck$Emulator;->WARNING:Lcom/stripe/android/stripe3ds2/init/Warning;

    .line 13
    .line 14
    return-void

.end method


.method public constructor <init>()V
    .locals 1

    .line 1
    sget-object v0, Lcom/stripe/android/stripe3ds2/init/SecurityCheck$Emulator;->WARNING:Lcom/stripe/android/stripe3ds2/init/Warning;

    .line 2
    .line 3
    invoke-direct {p0, v0}, Lcom/stripe/android/stripe3ds2/init/SecurityCheck;-><init>(Lcom/stripe/android/stripe3ds2/init/Warning;)V

    .line 4
    .line 5
    .line 6
    return-void
.end method


# virtual methods
.method public final check()Z
    .locals 5

    .line 1
    sget-object v0, Landroid/os/Build;->FINGERPRINT:Ljava/lang/String;

    .line 2
    .line 3
    const-string v1, "FINGERPRINT"

    .line 4
    .line 5
    invoke-static {v0, v1}, Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;->checkNotNullExpressionValue(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 6
    .line 7
    .line 8
    const-string v2, "generic"

    .line 9
    .line 10
    const/4 v3, 0x0

    .line 11
    invoke-static {v0, v2, v3}, Lkotlin/text/StringsKt__StringsJVMKt;->startsWith(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z

    .line 12
    .line 13
    .line 14
    move-result v4

    .line 15
    if-nez v4, :cond_1

    .line 16
    .line 17
    invoke-static {v0, v1}, Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;->checkNotNullExpressionValue(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 18
    .line 19
    .line 20
    const-string v1, "unknown"

    .line 21
    .line 22
    invoke-static {v0, v1, v3}, Lkotlin/text/StringsKt__StringsJVMKt;->startsWith(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z

    .line 23
    .line 24
    .line 25
    move-result v0

    .line 26
    if-nez v0, :cond_1

    .line 27
    .line 28
    sget-object v0, Landroid/os/Build;->MODEL:Ljava/lang/String;

    .line 29
    .line 30
    const-string v1, "MODEL"

    .line 31
    .line 32
    invoke-static {v0, v1}, Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;->checkNotNullExpressionValue(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 33
    .line 34
    .line 35
    const-string v4, "Emulator"

    .line 36
    .line 37
    invoke-static {v0, v4, v3}, Lkotlin/text/StringsKt__StringsKt;->contains(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Z)Z

    .line 38
    .line 39
    .line 40
    move-result v4

    .line 41
    if-nez v4, :cond_1

    .line 42
    .line 43
    invoke-static {v0, v1}, Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;->checkNotNullExpressionValue(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 44
    .line 45
    .line 46
    const-string v4, "Android SDK built for x86"

    .line 47
    .line 48
    invoke-static {v0, v4, v3}, Lkotlin/text/StringsKt__StringsKt;->contains(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Z)Z

    .line 49
    .line 50
    .line 51
    move-result v4

    .line 52
    if-nez v4, :cond_1

    .line 53
    .line 54
    invoke-static {v0, v1}, Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;->checkNotNullExpressionValue(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 55
    .line 56
    .line 57
    const-string v1, "google_sdk"

    .line 58
    .line 59
    invoke-static {v0, v1, v3}, Lkotlin/text/StringsKt__StringsKt;->contains(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Z)Z

    .line 60
    .line 61
    .line 62
    move-result v0

    .line 63
    if-nez v0, :cond_1

    .line 64
    .line 65
    sget-object v0, Landroid/os/Build;->MANUFACTURER:Ljava/lang/String;

    .line 66
    .line 67
    const-string v4, "MANUFACTURER"

    .line 68
    .line 69
    invoke-static {v0, v4}, Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;->checkNotNullExpressionValue(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 70
    .line 71
    .line 72
    const-string v4, "Genymotion"

    .line 73
    .line 74
    invoke-static {v0, v4, v3}, Lkotlin/text/StringsKt__StringsKt;->contains(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Z)Z

    .line 75
    .line 76
    .line 77
    move-result v0

    .line 78
    if-nez v0, :cond_1

    .line 79
    .line 80
    sget-object v0, Landroid/os/Build;->BRAND:Ljava/lang/String;

    .line 81
    .line 82
    const-string v4, "BRAND"

    .line 83
    .line 84
    invoke-static {v0, v4}, Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;->checkNotNullExpressionValue(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 85
    .line 86
    .line 87
    invoke-static {v0, v2, v3}, Lkotlin/text/StringsKt__StringsJVMKt;->startsWith(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z

    .line 88
    .line 89
    .line 90
    move-result v0

    .line 91
    if-eqz v0, :cond_0

    .line 92
    .line 93
    sget-object v0, Landroid/os/Build;->DEVICE:Ljava/lang/String;

    .line 94
    .line 95
    const-string v4, "DEVICE"

    .line 96
    .line 97
    invoke-static {v0, v4}, Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;->checkNotNullExpressionValue(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 98
    .line 99
    .line 100
    invoke-static {v0, v2, v3}, Lkotlin/text/StringsKt__StringsJVMKt;->startsWith(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z

    .line 101
    .line 102
    .line 103
    move-result v0

    .line 104
    if-nez v0, :cond_1

    .line 105
    .line 106
    :cond_0
    sget-object v0, Landroid/os/Build;->PRODUCT:Ljava/lang/String;

    .line 107
    .line 108
    invoke-static {v1, v0}, Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;->areEqual(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

    .line 109
    .line 110
    .line 111
    move-result v0

    .line 112
    if-eqz v0, :cond_2

    .line 113
    .line 114
    :cond_1
    const/4 v3, 0x0

    .line 115
    :cond_2
    return v3
.end method

i tried the v0 value to be null but didn't worked

You have posted a lot of code therefore it is not clear what you mean by "i tried the v0 value to be null".  Please describe what modification you are trying to do (what value do you get for an emulator and what do you want to set at which point instead) and code you already tried (include it in the posted code and add a comment to it).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
